# Condor OutOfMemoryError

Tags: python, opencv, distributed-computing, condor

I'm running some code to test if I can run the OpenCV library on a Condor system. It works fine when running `python testje.py` in the console. When submitting it on the condor system I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/data/condor/execute/dir_323648/condor_exec.exe", line 24, in <module>
    kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) /tmp/pip-req-build-3umofm98/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 48385936 bytes in function 'OutOfMemoryError'
```

So it failed to allocate 48MB of RAM?

When looking at the .log file:

```
Partitionable Resources :    Usage  Request Allocated 
   Cpus                 :                 1         1 
   Disk (KB)            :   192786   768000   1557164 
   Gpus (Average)       :                 0         0 
   Memory (MB)          :        0      500       512
```

I requested 500MB of RAM, there should be plenty.
Why does it crash?

---

#### All code (to be complete)

testje.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import pickle
import sys
import cv2

print('Starting')
# setup cv2
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
img = cv2.imread("0.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
print(img)

print('start calc')
# calc cv2
kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)
# calc np
norms = np.linalg.norm(des, axis=1)

# calc normal? python
index = []
for p in kp:
    temp = (p.pt, p.size, p.angle, p.response, p.octave, p.class_id)
    index.append(temp)


#store using pickle
with open('./random_dat.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump((123456, index, des, norms), handle)
    
print("finished")
```

**Note:**

OpenCV is imported by using `pip install ---target=my\python\dir\site-packages\ opencv-python` so that condor can transfer the library and import it as a local library.

Condor input:

```
#Normal execution
Universe = vanilla

#I need just one CPU (which is the default)
RequestCpus    = 1
#No GPU
RequestGPUs    = 0
#I need disk spqce KB
RequestDisk = 750MB
#I need 2 GBytes of RAM (resident memory)
RequestMemory  = 500MB
#It will not run longer than 1 day
+RequestWalltime = 150

#Transfer input files in cur_dir
transfer_input_files = 0.jpg, site-packages/

#retrieve data
should_transfer_files = YES
when_to_transfer_output = ON_EXIT

#I'm a nice person, I think...
NiceUser = true
#Mail me only if something is wrong
Notification = Always

# The job will 'cd' to this directory before starting, be sure you can _write_ here.
initialdir = /users/students/r0xxxxxx/Documents/testing_condor/
# This is the executable or script I want to run
executable = /users/students/r0xxxxxx/Documents/testing_condor/testje.py

#Output of condors handling of the jobs, will be in 'initialdir'
Log          = condor_bin.log
#Standard output of the 'executable', in 'initialdir'
Output       = condor_bin.out
#Standard error of the 'executable', in 'initialdir'
Error        = condor_bin.err

# Start just 1 instance of the job
Queue 1
```

Full condor log:

```
...
000 (3xx.xxx.xxx) 2021-07-19 16:20:57 Job submitted from host: <10.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx?addrs=10.xx.xx.xxx-xxxx&alias=name.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.be&noUDP&sock=schedd_xxxx_xxxx>
...
040 (3xx.xxx.xxx) 2021-07-19 16:21:15 Started transferring input files
    Transferring to host: <10.87.24.13:9618?addrs=10.xx.xx.xx-xxxx&alias=other.xxxx.xxxxxx.be&noUDP&sock=slotx_x_xxxxxx_xxxx_xxxx>
...
040 (3xx.xxx.xxx) 2021-07-19 16:21:19 Finished transferring input files
...
001 (3xx.xxx.xxx) 2021-07-19 16:21:20 Job executing on host: <10.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx?addrs=10.xx.xx.xx-xxxx&alias=other.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.be&noUDP&sock=startd_xxxx_xxxx>
...
006 (3xx.xxx.xxx) 2021-07-19 16:21:22 Image size of job updated: 1
    0  -  MemoryUsage of job (MB)
    0  -  ResidentSetSize of job (KB)
...
040 (3xx.xxx.xxx) 2021-07-19 16:21:22 Started transferring output files
...
040 (3xx.xxx.xxx) 2021-07-19 16:21:22 Finished transferring output files
...
005 (3xx.xxx.xxx) 2021-07-19 16:21:22 Job terminated.
    (1) Normal termination (return value 1)
        Usr 0 00:00:01, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Run Remote Usage
        Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Run Local Usage
        Usr 0 00:00:01, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Total Remote Usage
        Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Total Local Usage
    566  -  Run Bytes Sent By Job
    197400704  -  Run Bytes Received By Job
    566  -  Total Bytes Sent By Job
    197400704  -  Total Bytes Received By Job
    Partitionable Resources :    Usage  Request Allocated 
       Cpus                 :                 1         1 
       Disk (KB)            :   192786   768000   1557164 
       Gpus (Average)       :                 0         0 
       Memory (MB)          :        0      500       512 

    Job terminated of its own accord at 2021-07-19T14:21:22Z.
...
```

python prints:

```
Starting
[[ 21  83  40 ...   2  36  57]
 [ 42  51  27 ...  53  44  28]
 [ 60  31 127 ...  46  28  20]
 ...
 [103  80  22 ...  26  58 105]
 [ 58  63  47 ...  44  49  66]
 [ 48  49  56 ...  64  51  57]]
start calc
```

Comment: what is "Condor"? is this a supercomputer/cluster? who administers it? your university should offer support for its facilities.

Comment: Condor or more specifically HTCondor (https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/) is the software used to manage distributive computing on my university. Besides a wiki there is technical support, but this seems like an error on my part, that's why I posted it here.

Comment: from my experience with clusters, I'd say you didn't request enough RAM (or any) and your processes run into the default limit. if you are aiming to get entire nodes anyway, set all the limits to what the node ought to have (minus OS overhead). "usage 0" (or RAM) puzzles me but who knows how that's measured.

Comment: I'll try just adding more RAM tomorrow, I've ran `cv.kmeans()` succesfully which did show a few RAM as used, I'm guessing that the code before the error line doesn't even require 1 RAM rounded in total? The problem seems to be specifically at the `sift.detectAndComput()` :(